# XHTML multi-column text flow div

Tags: xhtml, cross-browser, multiple-columns

How can I have multi-column text flow in div for XHTML please? (if possible)

I'm looking for a cross-browser specification.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a `<table>`.

Comment: @LarsH: Sounds like you haven't been following webdesign for the last decade or so.

Comment: There is no reason to be mean. Thanks for the answer, LarsH, but although a table would do the trick if content was predictible, I cannot use it as the user will input the text as a whole rather than split in two.

Comment: @Epcylon, sounds like you fell on the kneejerk tables=evil bandwagon. FYI I don't think the original q said "text flow". Or else I missed it. Thanks @Francisc.

Comment: I wasn't refering to text flow, but any number of other reasons for why using tables for layout is a bad idea. See for instance these links: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tableless_web_design, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html, http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/

Comment: Yup, I edited the question as it was very unclear and I'm sorry for that.

Comment: @Epcylon, "why using tables for layout is a bad idea". The original q did not specify "layout". There are good and well-known reasons not to abuse tables **to control page layout**, but that use was not specified in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no cross-browser compatible HTML/CSS based way. People are working on it, see: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/ but support is experimental.

Comment: Yup, I saw that, thanks. But I need one that's CSS2 or 2.1 tops.

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of the many techniques documented pretty much all over the internet. Some quick suggestions:

- [The Perfect Multi-Column Stacked Liquid Layout](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-stacked-columns.htm)
- [TUTORIAL: Multi-Column Layout Using CSS Float](http://www.ozzu.com/html-tutorials/tutorial-multi-column-layout-using-css-float-part-t85704.html)
- [EASY MULTI-COLUMN DESIGNS USING CSS 2.1 DISPLAY PROPERTIES](http://pvii.com/tutorials/css/3-column-flex-display/index.htm)

Comment: Thank you, Epcylon. I'll take a look and comeback with a `verdict`.

Comment: Hm, what I meant was for text flow. I'll edit the question to be more clear. Thank you and sorry.